# Data From multiple FutureBuilders in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm fetching data from an api source , the data is fetched properly , then i store the data in sqflite , so basically after doing both , i need to check if there is connection so that i show data from internet other than that i get data back from database , now  since i'm using futurebuilder which return internet async operation result , how would i be also to get list of data from database , any help is appreciated guys and thank you in advance.

- This is what i have tried so far

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbHelper = DbHelper();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
       return Scaffold (
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("News Application"),
           centerTitle: true,
           backgroundColor: Colors.black,
           titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
         ),
         body: FutureBuilder  (
           future: Future.wait([getEverything(),dbHelper.getAllNews()]),
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot)  {
             if(snapshot.hasError) {
               // So basically here if there is an error , i woul like to show data from database
               // i tried to get data from snapshot like this : snapshot.data[0]...and snapshot.data[1]
               // but no data is returned..
               return new Center(
                 child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                   backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                 ),
               );
             } else {
               if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                 return new Container(
                     color: Colors.black,
                     child:  GridView.count(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                         crossAxisCount: 2,
                         children: List.generate(snapshot.data.articles.length, (index) {
                           return new GestureDetector(
                             onTap: (){
                               Navigator.push(
                                   context,
                                   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                                     image:  snapshot.data.articles[index].urlToImage,
                                     author:  snapshot.data.articles[index].author,
                                     title:  snapshot.data.articles[index].title,
                                     description:  snapshot.data.articles[index].description,
                                     publishedAt:  snapshot.data.articles[index].publishedAt,
                                     content:  snapshot.data.articles[index].content,
                                   ))
                               );
                             },
                             child:  Card(
                               elevation: 12,
                               child:  new Column(
                                 children: [
                                   Image.network(snapshot.data.articles[index].urlToImage,
                                     width: 250,),
                                   Text(snapshot.data.articles[index].description)
                                 ],
                               ),
                             ),
                           );
                         }
                         )));
               }
             }
            return new Center(
              child: Visibility(
                visible: true,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
              ),
            );
           },
         ),
       );
  }
```

Comment: write an `async` method where you check for internet connection and if Internet is available return data from your web api or from sqlite otherwise, that method returns a `Future` that you will use in your `FutureBuilder`

Comment: so should i set the future return type to dynamic ? because i'm getting list of data from internet but only save few values not all so basically not list , just string , could the return type be dynamic here ? thank you

Comment: it should be the same list in both cases - that way your future builder doesn't even know where your data come from

Comment: exactly that's why i got stuck because the return type of both futures are not the same ..no other way to handle this ?

Comment: so use `await` to get the data of other type and then return it converted to final list, more https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await